# "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Passing DTO object having two arrays from angular to spring boot rest but getting error "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`"

Having below dto in angular

but JSON.stringify() not generating valid json.

```
export interface SampleDTO{
    carList:Array<Car>;
    addList:Array<Address>;
}
```

JSON I am deserializing:

```
{"addList":"[{"city":"ABAD","pin":"384567"},{"city":"ABAD","pin":"384567"}]","carList":"[{"name":"Honda","cc":"360"},{"name":"Honda","cc":"360"}]"}
```

Spring Boot Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/get")
ResponseEntity<String> sample(@RequestBody SampleDTO sampleDTO)
```

Pojo :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class SampleDTO implements Serializable {

    private List<Address> addList;

    private List<Car> carList;

    public List<Address> getAddList() {
        return addList;
    }

    public void setAddList(List<Address> addList) {
        this.addList = addList;
    }

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }

    public void setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList = carList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of the JSON, the code which is failing, and the java data structure if any that you're trying to produce from the JSON.

Comment: And it'll be nice if you could show your controller aswell

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks

Comment: OK why did i see the double quote wrapping the arrays? Yes, that's the reason.

Comment: But why angular's JSON.stringify() behaving like this?